# Ubuntu 14.04LTS updates

Tags: 14.04, updates

Recently I've experienced a wifi connection crash, after a routine update. After some unsuccessful trials as recommended by users, I had to reinstall Ubuntu.

Now I have again automatic recommendations to install updates (including network updates) and I do not know what to do.

Should I install them, with a chance of getting again the network crash, or could I install everything but the network updates?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a dual boot with same version, so have one to test and the other to fall back on. I've had moderate success with that method figuring out hardware issues with Ubuntu 10.

Comment: For now I've deselected all updates which include "network" word. I am not sure how important the deselected updates are, so I still need some advice.